# How to check if a string contains binary data?

Tags: python

Consider, I have a string which has some binary data of the following form:

```
n\xe1v\u011bsy a p\u0159\xedv\u011bsy Tlumi\u010de pro autobusy
```

Now I want to identify, if a string has binary data or not. I am trying the following code:

```
def isBinary(line):
    print line
    return "xe" in line
```

But this does not work. How can I effectively identify if a string contains binary data or not.

Comment: First ask yourself why you wrote the value like you did and not `návěsy a přívěsy Tlumiče pro autobusy`

Comment: the thing is, I get this data in a json file for some key. sometime this contain binary data like the above. I want to identify when i have binary data when I have meaningful string.

Comment: Are you on Python 2 or 3? Is this simply an issue of how strings are being represented in a data structure printing? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am using python 2.7. I am trying to identify if a string is banary data or not.

Comment: No. I already know what you are *asking* I want to know what overarching thing you want to accomplish. I suspect this might be the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: See here's the thing. It's always "binary data". The strings are meaningful. Since you are on Python 2 you'll need to explicitly use `unicode` objects decoded properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can't look for the substring 'xe' because '\xe[0-9]' is actually just a representation of a special character.

Instead could check whether the ASCII value of each character is within desired ranges. e.g. if I only wanted alphabetical characters:

```
for c in input_str:
  ascii_val = ord(c)
  upper = range(65, 91)
  lower = range(97, 123)
  if ord(c) not in upper and ord(c) not in lower:
    print("NON-ALPHABETICAL CHARACTER FOUND!")
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `"\xe1" in line`, which will look for the byte value 0xE1 in the line. But you really have to define "binary data"; what constitutes text data and what is binary? Let's suppose your definition is "ASCII" - that is to say, anything 0x80 or above marks it as binary. In that case:

```
def is_binary(line): # PEP 8 naming - snake_words not mixedCase
    return any(ord(x) > 0x80 for x in line)
```

You might also want to check if there's a "\x00" in the line, as that often signifies binary data.

```
def is_binary(line):
    return "\x00" in line or any(ord(x) > 0x80 for x in line)
```